# How to track HTTP and HTTPS from the same Google Analytics account?

Tags: google-analytics, https, http

I have a website with tutorials and a discuss forum. The website load on http protocol and the forum load with https for security reasons.
For both of them I run the default Google Analytics code, but I saw that the forum it's mot tracked. Besides that, in Analytics, landing pages are noted very weird:

```
/forum/http://my-address.com 
or
/article_id/http://my-address.com
or
category/article_id/http://my-address.com
```

The tutorial site is like `http://example.com` and the forum is like `https://example.com/forum`
Can I track both of them with only one Analytics account?

Answer (score 1):

Google Analytics tracks HTTP and HTTPS with it's default configuration. So I think it's likely that your problems are some other configuration of your Analytics code.